# What is the correct way to use keepalive http connection with `requests`?

Tags: python

I am using python3 with requests library for rest communication. In order to improve performance I am using https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects session object to reuse the connection. I create one instance of session and use it to send rest GET request for every users' request.

However when the request rate is reaching 100 request per second, I start getting "connection abort" error. The trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

It seems like it reaches the maximum capacity of the connection pool. I wonder how I can handle this error.

It works fine if I don't use session object. Use `requests.post` for every request.

The code looks like. So the `session` instance is created at very beginning and is reused inside the class method.

```
session = requests.Session()

class MyClass:
    def send(self):
         ...
         session.post(...)
```

The server is a python Flask application with uwsgi. I enabled the keep-alive connection with the command:

```
uwsgi \
  --uid uwsgi \
  --master \
  --plugins http,python3,stats_pusher_statsd \
  --http :8880 \
  --buffer-size 32768 \
  --enable-threads \
  --processes 1 \
  --so-keepalive \
  --wsgi-file uwsgi.py
```

Do I need to make any changes on the server side in order to make it work?

Comment: what if server doesn't like bots/scripts and it blocks your requests?

Comment: It works fine if I don't use session object.

Comment: have you tried to use the `SESSION` object from `request`?

Comment: @Mox Isn’t that what they are currently doing?

Comment: If the server is not your own one, it is normal that they want to abort your connections as you are making too many connections. Not much to do actually based on the current structure except slowing down.

Comment: why does it work without `session` object? It works fine with `requests.post` for every request. I think using `requests.post` create more connection than `session` because it doesn't persist any connections.

Comment: **[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**  it seems the server's issue. I guess the request rate would be different between using **session (use connection pool)** and **requests.post**, the latter would create a new connection every time, which would be a bit slower. So could you share how to do requests concurrently, use threading? and record the request rate in these two cases.

Comment: It seems like a server error but I have enabled keep alive on the uwgi in server side. Currently code application is running as a single process and single thread, I am not enabling any thread model.